# How to get parent array length in component? AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

If I have a property in the parent and want to access that value in the component, how would I be able to do that?

Parent:

```
export class Animal{
  animalID ?: Array<number>;
{
```

Child:

```
import {Component, Input} from '@angular/core';

import {Animal} from '../animal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-animal',
  templateUrl: './animal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./animal.component.css']
})
export class AnimalComponent {
  @Input() animal: Animal;
  public totalAnimals = animal.animalID.length;
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<mat-card class="animal">
  <mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-title>{{animal.animalID}}</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-subtitle>Total Animals: {{totalAnimals}}</mat-card-subtitle>
  </mat-card-header>
  <mat-card-content>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

However, it cannot access that numberAnimals array in order to get the length. If someone could help me that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is `numberAnimals`?

Comment: sorry I meant to write animalID there, it's fixed now.

Comment: Please create a fiddleor stackblitz to demonstrate your problem

Comment: can you show the html?

Comment: I pasted it over into stackblitz, its my first time using it so I'm sorry if it's not perfect.

Comment: @techguy I added the html to the post as well

Answer (score 0):

Because property 'animal' is used before its initialization. You should set value in *OnInit()*. If 'animal' is called from request API, at this time child component is initialized, 'animal' is undefined, you should check this in *ngOnChanges* life cycle hook or check animal is not empty to show child component

```
export class AnimalComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() animal: Animal;
 public totalAnimals: number = 0;

 constructor() {}

 ngOnInit(): void {
  this.totalAnimals = animal?.animalID.length;
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for responding! However, it is still saying that animal is undefinied in the ngOnInit function

Comment: if so then it's likely that it's broken in the parent component. Can u share parent component code (HTML and Typescript)

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases that we need to catch *Input* changes in child component, which is why Angular provides ***[ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)*** Lifecycle hook.

Please remove this initial assigning value

```
public totalAnimals: number = 0;
```

Add `ngOnChanges` to detect when ever your input changes

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.animal) {
      console.log(changes.animal.currentValue);
      // you can check object value and make appr. changes here
      this.totalAnimals = changes.animal.currentValue?.animalID.length;
    }
  }
```

Also add value in ngOnInit() to make sure that you get first value

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.totalAnimals = animal?.animalID?.length;
}
```

You can check more about Input here: [**detect-input-property-changes**](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/detect-input-property-changes-ngonchanges-setters)